# Unable to use a decorator into a NestJS service

Tags: decorator, nestjs

Why we cant use an decorator within a NestJS service? Here is a example on how I tried to do, but it does not work.

Decorator: @User()

```
// user.decorator.ts
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator((data, req): {userId, email} => {
  return data ? req.user[data] : req.user;
});
```

When I call this decorator into a service, I got this message: **Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression**

```
// connect.service.ts
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from '../account/user/user.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectService {
 @User() 
 userInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add a decorator on an Injectable() I don't think you can do that.  It would need to be on a method so that when it is called some magic can happen behind the scenes.  Consider using class-validator and the validationPipe
For example:

```
@Get('vitalsByEncounterID')
async getVitalsByEncounterID(@Query() params: VitalsByEncounterPathDTO, @Headers(DFDHeaders.xRequestId) requestId: string): Promise<VitalSignsDTO[]> {}
```

Then you'd decorate the class

```
export class VitalsByEncounterPathDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({ required: true, description: 'iCentra id for the patient' })
  patientId: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({ required: true, description: 'an encounter id for the patient' })
  encounterId: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decorate a property with a `ParamDecorator`, that's why you get this error message.

Can you give some more details on your usecase? That would maybe help someone to give some insights on what you're trying to achieve.